# Can't access webserver of airflow after run the container

Tags: docker, airflow

I pulled the latest version of airflow image from docker hub.

`apache/airflow`.

And I tried to run a container base on this image.

`docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 apache/airflow webserver`

The container is running and the status of port is fine. But I still can't access the airflow webserver from my browser.
[image: docker ps]

This site can’t be reached.
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

After few minutes, the container will stop automatically.

Is there anyone could advise?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this?  Are there any interesting logs from the container?  Is the service inside the container actually listening on port 5000?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have experience with airflow, but this is how you fix this image to run:

First of all you have to overwrite the entrypoint because the existing one doesn't help a lot. From what I understand this image needs 2 steps in order to run: initdb and webserver. For this reason the existing entrypoint is not useful.

Run:

```
docker run -p 5000:8080 --entrypoint /bin/bash -ti  apache/airflow
```

This will open a shell inside a running container. Also note that I mapped port 8080 inside the container.

Then inside the container run:

```
airflow db init
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

Note that in older versions of airflow, the command to initialize the database is `airflow initdb`, instead of `airflow db init`.

Open a browser and navigate to http://localhost:5000

When you close the container your work is gone thou ;)

Another thing you can do is put the 2 airflow commands in a bash script and map that script inside the container and use it as entrypoint. Something like this:

```
docker run -p 5000:8080 -v $(pwd)/startup.sh:/opt/airflow/startup.sh --entrypoint /opt/airflow/startup.sh -d --name airflow apache/airflow
```

You should make startup.sh executable before running this.

Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! It works! And I learned a lot after reading related document and Dockerfile.

Comment: What I found is that there is no apache/airflow:latest docker image (it defaults to :latest if no tag is supplied). So you have to choose one such as `:apache/airflow:master-python3.7-ci`
The command to init the database has also changed to:
`airflow db init`

Comment: thanks, it worked. small change  airflow initdb == > airflow db init